# SQL Server 2008 - Insert from .txt or .csv with specific columns

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to insert from a .txt file (or .csv would be better!) but I want to be able to pick specific columns from the .txt (or .csv file), such as column #1 #2 #5 #10 etc..

Is this possible to do?

At the minute the following MSSQL will insert the entire contents and requires matching number of fields on the database it is inserting into.

```
BULK
INSERT TableName
FROM 'C:\Users\User\Desktop\test.txt'
WITH
(
FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
)
GO
```

Here is an example of one row of data from the .csv:-

```
"1A","SOUTH BANK UNIVERSITY","","","","103","","BOROUGH ROAD","","","","LONDON","","SURREY","SOUTHWARK","1","L","38026","SE1 0AA","53180","17940","BEGE","Q71","08Q  ","064"
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Use SSIS. You can either setup a repeatable package or just use the data import wizard (which uses SSIS).

Comment: I would use [OPENROWSET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190312(v=sql.100).aspx) and specify a [FORMATFILE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178129(v=sql.100).aspx)

Comment: Taking a closer look, I see your data is enclosed in double quotes.  That makes my suggestion a bit tougher.  But it's still do-able.  SSIS may be preferred.

Comment: Sometimes the best solution is to go ahead and import every row and column into a staging table, and then copy the rows/columns you want from the staging table into your final destination table with a SQL command.

Comment: Thanks @TabAlleman - don't know why I didn't think of doing this!

Answer (score 0):

You can use OPENROWSET
You'll need the Microsoft.ACE.OLDB.xx.0 provider installed.
(xx on my server = 15.0, or 12.0)

If your file does not have column names:

```
SELECT F1, F2, F5, F10
FROM OPENROWSET (
'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.15.0', 
'Text;Database=C:\Projects\data;Extended Properties="HDR=No;IMEX=1"',
'SELECT * FROM data.txt') a
```

If your file has column names (specify the name of the column)

```
SELECT Column1, Column2, Column5, Column10
FROM OPENROWSET (
'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.15.0', 
'Text;Database=C:\Projects\data;Extended Properties="HDR=Yes;IMEX=1"',
'SELECT * FROM data.txt') a
```

You'll need to enable 'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries' using sp_configure

```
EXEC sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1
RECONFIGURE
GO
EXEC sp_configure 'ad hoc distributed queries', 1
RECONFIGURE
GO
```

You also might have to "allow in process" under the provider properties. 
(Server Object | Linked Servers | Providers)

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you save your data into a csv or excel format, you can use the SQL Server Management Studio function to import the data from your sheet with a wizard instead of using commands.

To access this function, right click on your database, then Tasks -> Import Data.  Choose "Flat File Source" on the next page if you wish to use your .txt/.csv file.  Choose Excel if you want to save your csv as an Excel file and import that instead.

Just follow the wizard from there.  You can import the columns into a new or existing table.

As a thought, it is probably easier to save your csv file into Excel and then just manually delete the columns you don't need prior to the import.